# How to record a div + audio input on mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, screen-capture

I'm Kevin, a Junior Web Dev.

I have a project which include Drawing a Game Canvas over a Camera Canvas, something that looks like this:
[image: game canvas]

To simplify, it's implemented pseudo-ly like this:

```
<div class="container" style="position: relative"> 
   <canvas class="camera-canvas" style="position: absolute"></canvas>
   <canvas class="game-canvas" style="position: absolute"></canvas>
   <p class="score" style="position: absolute">Score: 159</p>
</div>
```

Because the game will be played on **mobile browser**, how do I record the outer container **+ mic audio input**?

The player has to be able to record the gameplay for about 15s,

I already seen this SO post:
[Is it possible to record a video of the contents of an HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56687953/is-it-possible-to-record-a-video-of-the-contents-of-an-html-element)

but I don't understand the meaning at:

> If you don't have a canvas element and you need to record an HTML
> element, you would first need to place a hidden canvas on the screen
> and draw on it your HTML content using window.requestAnimationFrame().
> Then you can use RecordRTC to record that canvas element.
>
> You can use RecordRTC's CanvasRecorder to record just the canvas.
>
> But if you want to do other things like record the user's microphone
> or browser tab's audio alongside your recording your canvas, you can
> canvas.captureStream() and use the RecordRTC's MediaStreamRecorder to
> record.

Image taken from zaleos blog at:
https://blog.zaleos.net/game-with-camera-controller/

For simplicity, I want to record this demo on mobile browser:
https://league55.github.io/fruit-ninja-blog-post-demo/

Answer (score 0):

With Js to record a video with audio use this =>
Add a video tag
And set its position exactly as canvas position

Js =>

```
const consts = {
audio: true, // ALLOW AUDIO
video: true // ALLOW VIDEO
}
window.navigator.getMediaDevices(consts).then((src) => {
cameraRecord.srcObject = src
})
```

Reference =>  [GO TO](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices)

Comment: For Recording the video go there use MEDIARECORDER (PERMISSION) [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder)

Comment: @Kevin Tanudjaja Media recorder can also record content of html